# Libgdx GWT 2.8 Compiling Issues

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I'm trying to superDev compile a 'working' GWT Libgdx project that has recently succumb to a potential file and/or library issues upon updating to LibGDX 1.9.6, GWT 2.8.0, and jre1.8.0_121.

Here is the error trace when compiling:

```
GET /recompile/html
   Job com.client.GdxDefinitionSuperdev_1_0
      starting job: com.client.GdxDefinitionSuperdev_1_0
      binding: locale=default
      binding: user.agent=safari
      binding: web.sockets=true
      Compiling module com.client.GdxDefinitionSuperdev
         Unification traversed 1638 fields and methods and 361 types. 36 are considered part of the current module and 42 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
         Compiling 1 permutation
            Compiling permutation 0...
            [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.HasName$1.compare(HasName.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.HasName$1.compare(HasName.java:30)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JTypeOracle.getCastableDestinationTypes(JTypeOracle.java:734)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.ComputeExhaustiveCastabilityInformation.createCompleteCastMap(ComputeExhaustiveCastabilityInformation.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.ComputeExhaustiveCastabilityInformation.execImpl(ComputeExhaustiveCastabilityInformation.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.ComputeExhaustiveCastabilityInformation.exec(ComputeExhaustiveCastabilityInformation.java:32)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.normalizeSemantics(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:364)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:272)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilePerms.compile(CompilePerms.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            [ERROR] Unrecoverable exception, shutting down
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationProblemReporter.logAndTranslateException(CompilationProblemReporter.java:112)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:459)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:272)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilePerms.compile(CompilePerms.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            [ERROR] Not all permutation were compiled , completed (0/1)
      [WARN] recompile failed
      [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

I located this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.HasName$1.compare(HasName.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.HasName$1.compare(HasName.java:30)
```

line of code, (which I located in my 'Referenced Libraries' folder) while on the hunt for a potential line number mismatch (maybe there is?).

Anyway, that line of code references this source:

[image: https://puu.sh/vgaVZ/77df4df233.png]

It is as if there is some library version mismatch or incompatibility. I don't really know how to debug this further as I'm not an expert with gradle and the whole project structure tied into GWT's magic.

Here are the project libraries .. **I have a strong feeling that something isn't quite right.**:

([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/YwQHq90f) - build.gradle in html folder)

([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/PBCmQ4Fx) - build.gradle in top project folder)

[image]

[image]

Been stuck on this for hours so any hints or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why `compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"` in your core ?

Comment: I've found the answer I plan on updating this tomorrow - guava 18 is not supported with the other dependencies. Changing to guava 20 fixed it. But as to your comment, I'm not sure - I was messing around with tons of things. Is that line unnecessary?

Comment: I think so, that line is unnecessary there